# Manipulate MySQL Database via Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, xhtml

Good Evening. I'm having a challenge trying to display a database from "MySql" to a web page via "Netbeans" so that people can add/edit/remove the data. The code that I'm using is "xhtml". So far. I'm only able to display the data from the database.

Thank You in advance